# Clipping DEM model in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, model

I have created a model that takes a point layer that contains elevation data, then interpolate it using TIN and then clip the results according to shapefile.
The problem is that the model works and does the TIN, but for some reason the clip failed all the time.
I made sure everything is on the same projection so that's not the problem.

here is a screenshot of the model error message-
[image]

I know it says that the error is with the tin. but whenever I run the model without the clip it works.

this is my model-

[image]

Edit-

this is the error message I get after clip the raster manually-

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the clipping manually? If so, what is the outcome?

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work on QGIS 3.8 but in QGIS 3.4 it works partially, it creates the raster but when I try to clip by mask layer manually I get the error message which I put on the original post I posted

Comment: Maybe your clipping layer has a faulty geometry?

Comment: Please always include error messages as text, not screenshots. This is so they're searchable.